# gcc or cc no longer seems to work in 12.04 lts

Tags: 12.04, gcc

I recently installed 12.04 LTS and I would like to compile short c programs.

When I enter gcc or cc at the command promp to compile a simple test program "test.c"I get the following:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\234’ in program
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\342’ in program
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
test.c:6:1: error: stray ‘\235’ in program
test.c:6:11: error: ‘Test’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:6:11: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Do I need to install other software (other than gcc?

sincerely,

Bruce

Answer (score 1):

You should look at line 6 of your code, and **re-type** it. It would solve the problem.

Here is an excerpt from [http://www.giannistsakiris.com](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/index.php/2008/04/17/gcc-error-stray-%E2%80%98342%E2%80%99-in-program/):

> The errors were of this form:
>
> ```
>  giannis@giannis-vbox:~$ gcc
> program.c program.c: In function ‘main’: program.c:57: error: stray
> ‘\342’ in program program.c:57: error: stray ‘\200’ in program
> program.c:57: error: stray ‘\234’ in program program.c:57: error:
> stray ‘\’ in program
> ```
>
> I couldn't see any obvious syntactical error in the mentioned line.
>   This is how line #57 looks like:
>
> ```
> printf(“\nThe linked list representation is...\n”);
> ```
>
> At first sight, it looks pretty fine, but if you look closely you will
>   see that the double quotation marks that surround the string literal
>   are not the neutral (vertical) ones (like this: "). They are left and
>   right double quotation marks respectively.
>
> If I replace the quotation marks with the neutral ones, like this:
>
> ```
> printf("\nThe linked list representation is...\n");
> ```
>
> the problem is solved. So, if you are getting this kind of error maybe
>   you should look closely to any double (or single) quotation marks in
>   the erroneous line.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with your code. Not gcc, from what I can tell it's working properly.

Something like the wrong characters? Make sure you're using ' and not ´ etc.